# A puzzle where you must find the mate in 3 solution but avoid mate in 2 and mate in 1 solutions?

Tags: problems, checkmate

I want to see if a puzzle could exist where you must avoid finding mate in 1 or 2 but just find the mate in 3 solution.

This is not subjective it is a hard math problem to make a move that forces mate in 3 while avoiding other moves that force an earlier mate

Comment: Maybe you can express this more elegantly: a puzzle where there is a mate in 1, and mate in 2 & a mate in 3?

Comment: Laska, Rewan, you simply could have linked to the relevant MatPlusForum thread :-) (Or do I misunderstand the intention of the author?) 8/3N1p2/8/2N2P2/p1Pk4/p2p1p2/B2PPPp1/6K1 HR, MPF May 10 2020

Answer (score 1):

```
6k1/4Q3/6K1/8/8/8/8/8 w - - 0 1
```

Just take n moves, without threefold repetition, doing a king walk that goes back to g6 or h6. Then Qg7#. This will be your forced checkmate in n+1 moves.

EDIT:

```
k1B5/r2rrrrr/R7/R7/R1N5/R7/R6B/K7 w - - 0 2
```

Comment: the solution is far from unique, though.

Comment: @NoamD.Elkies The new position I added should be a unique mate in three